# IE9 HTTPS security is compromised by http://v.zilionfast.in

Tags: security, https, internet-explorer-9

I have a problem with https security in IE9 only... the message talk about an url that doesn't exist in my code "http://v.zilionfast.in/257344370/?t=vrt". 
The issue was detected in different pc (in different networks) with IE9, some of them show the error message, others doesn't show anything.
I have no clue about what script is calling this url because i can't find it. Somebody have a clue about what is happening?

this is the code of the header basically:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="#rutaIni#/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="#rutaIni#/basicos.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="#rutaIni#/prototype-packed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="#rutaIni#/scriptaculous.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="#rutaIni#/glider.js"></script>
<script src="#rutaIni#/modalbox.js" type="/text/javascript"></script>
<link href="#rutaIni#/modalbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

the other part of the code is just a table that is filled with a query and some html (no problem with that).

thank you!!!

Comment: Where does the value `#rutaIni#` originate from?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this site is flagged by Vipre and other Internet Security and Antivirus programs to be malicious.  It is possible that your web browser has been infected or your code contains elements associated with the site.  The only way to know for sure is for you to post your code.

Comment: firts post edited with the header code... i hope this can help.

Comment: It's possible that the included Javascript sources contain a redirect or resources from the malicious site.  You may try doing a content search using Windows Explorer of your whole site, including Javascript files looking for the malicious URL.

Comment: thank you, i'll try it. i hope this search can help. i'll let you know if i find something.